# Checking validity of propositional statement

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

I was unable to solve this particular problem which asks to find the valid first order logic among below:

1. $\forall x(P(x)\to Q(x))\to (\forall xP(x)\to\forall xQ(x))$
2. $\exists x(P(x) \lor Q(x))\to (\exists xP(x) \to \exists xQ(x))$
3. $\exists x(P(x)\land Q(x)) \leftrightarrow (\exists xP(x)\land \exists xQ(x))$
4. $\forall x \exists y P(x,y) \to \exists y \forall xP(x,y)$

I interpret it as follows:

$P(x)$: $x$ is a princess

$Q(x)$: $x$ is a queen

1. $\forall x(P(x)\to Q(x))$: Anyone, who is a princess, is queen.

   $\forall xP(x)\to\forall xQ(x)$: If everyone is princess, then everyone is queen.
2. $\exists x(P(x) \lor Q(x))$: Someone is princess or queen (or both (as it is inclusive OR)).

   $(\exists xP(x) \to \exists xQ(x))$: If someone is princess then someone is queen.
3. $\exists x(P(x)\land Q(x))$: Someone is (both) princess and queen.

   $(\exists xP(x)\land \exists xQ(x))$: Someone is princess and someone (could be different one than the princess) is queen.
4. This I know for sure is incorrect:

   $\forall x \exists y P(x,y) \not \to \exists y \forall xP(x,y)$:

But I dont find any of these interpretations make any of four options valid. Am I making mistake?

Comment: Hint: 1. is valid, the others are not.

Comment: @Brian O can we prove that mathematically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one is correct. Keeping your example, if everyone who is a princess is also a queen, then if everybody is a princess then everybody is a queen ;)

Comment: ohhh seems correct now, can we prove this mathematically (or should I say symbolically) too, instead of taking help of verbal examples?

Comment: Sure, I would have posted a syntactic proof but I don't know the syntax to write it in a fancy way. The reasoning is (more or less) the following: from $\forall x (P(x) \to Q(x))$ deduce $P(x)\to Q(x)$, from $\forall x P(x)$ deduce $P(x)$, by modus ponens deduce $Q(x)$ and conclude $\forall x Q(x)$ by noticing that $x$ do not appear as free variable in the hypothesis from which you start.

Comment: Well man that was bummer for me. Please have a look at my name :'\ .  Anyways can you please point me to any similar proof online. If not very similar, thats fine, but it will at least be indicative how should I approach. btw if you need how to type $\LaTeX$ on stackexchange, here is [the guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Ops sorry, I thought you already knew how to write a syntactic proof in first order logic :). Here is how it should look like (just to make an example) http://www.logicmatters.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/proofsty062.gif . I fear there's no way to make this in MathJax (except by fractions of fractions, which is not a very nice solution).

Comment: May I ask you where you found those problems? Because if it's in a mathematical logic course then you should experience (sooner or later) examples of syntactic derivation, otherwise references will probably be too heavy to read just for curiosity. Anyway I may suggest you to take a look at Van Dalen's Logic and Structure, in which there are plenty of them.

Comment: It was asked in [GATE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graduate_Aptitude_Test_in_Engineering) exam.

Comment: And thanks for the reference :-)

Comment: I don't know the details about the GATE exam but it doesn't seem they would expect a purely formal proof, I guess a semi-formal proof would be enough. You can reason in this way: take any $y$ and assume $\forall x P(x)$ and $\forall x (P(x) \to Q(x))$ hold. From $\forall x P(x)$ you deduce $P(y)$ is true, so using $\forall x (P(x) \to Q(x))$ you can also deduce $Q(y)$ is true. Since the proof does not depend on the particular choice of $y$ you deduce $\forall y Q(y)$, i.e. $\forall x Q(x)$

Comment: actually I wanted an approach (may not be that formal) or say step by step algorithm which can surely lead to conclusion whether given statement is valid or not, the way we use resolution refutation to prove validity of the statements not involving quantifiers. An ad hoc approach requires experience to be able to do proper guesses. The exam is objective and I just need to be able to determine the validity. Where can I find the explanation of the gif you provided, I mean what it means, the procedure to draw it and determine validity of statements using it?