# Generating truth tables for quantifiers online

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

1. Is there any online tool that can generate truth tables for quatifiers (existential and universal). I can generate for Boolean equations not involving quantifier as [this one](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28P+%7C%7C+~Q%29+%26%26+%28P+%26%26+~Q+%7C%7C+P+%26%26+R%29+%26%26+%28~P+%26%26+~R+%7C%7C+~Q%29)? But I didnt find any example for quantifiers [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/examples/LogicSetTheory.html) and [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/examples/BooleanAlgebra.html).
2. Also can we specify more than one equations in wolframalpha, so that it can display truth values for more than one equations side by side in the same truth table as shown below? And also possibly show the truth value for each intermediate operator also shown below?

[image]

Comment: You may express all quantified statements in terms of more "elementary" logic and some set theory, for example $\forall x\in A: P(x)$ is equivalent to $x\in A\implies P(x)$.

Comment: @OskarLimka $\forall x\in A:P(x)$ is equivalent to $\forall x\,(x\in A\implies P(x))$. You probably intended $\forall x$ to be tacitly understood as part of the meaning of $\implies$. If so, that should be made clear to the OP since (s)he is likely to interpret $\implies$ by just a truth table.

Comment: @Andreas Blass quantifying $x$ in the second statement is ok (for emphasis), but it is not logically necessary. The $x$ in the statement $[x\in A\Rightarrow P(x)]$ is a dummy variable (so it doesn't need quantification) whereas in $[P(x)]$ it is not a dummy variable and we need to quantify it. I bracketed propositions.  Think of the following example $P(x):\Leftrightarrow [x\geq0]$ and $A:=\mathbb N$.

Comment: @OskarLimka Thanks for confirming my conjecture that you intended $\forall x$to be implicit in your formula (since you say $x$ is a dummy variable).  I still think it's good to make that clear to the OP, since the usual definitions would say that $x$ is free in $x\in A\implies P(x)$. But I think our comments have, collectively, made that clear enough.

Comment: @Andreas Blass Indeed. My rule of thumb redundancy-test (in logic) is to remove something and see if what remains still makes sense.  If we remove the quantified bit in $\forall x\in A:P(x)$, we're left with $P(x)$ which cannot be assigned a true/false value because $x$ is "dangling" (to borrow terms from computer science), so strictly speaking $P(x)$ is not a proposition but a indexed family of propositions (logic folks call a construction such as $P(x)$ "formula").  Whereas in $\forall x : x\in A\implies P(x)$ removing the quantifier leaves us with a proposition.

Comment: @Andreas Blass I'm not sure how "free" is defined in logic, but if a statement can be assigned true/false value, it means that it has no free variable. Example, in the proposition [If $V$ is a finite vector space then $V$ has a basis.] which we all know is true, I would conclude $V$ is not free.

Comment: @OskarLimka I think I understand your conventions, but you might want to check with a standard textbook in mathematical logic about the definition of "free variable". The usual convention in logic would say that $x$ is free in $x\in A\implies P(x)$, and that the truth value of this formula can depend on the value assigned to $x$. For example, if $A$ is the set of prime numbers and $P(x)$ is "$x>8$," then $x\in A\implies P(x)$ is true when $x$ has the value 4 or 9 or 11 but false when $x$ has the value 3. Only the quantified form $\forall x(x\in A\implies P(x))$ is simply false.

Answer (score 1):

The semantics for quantifiers are more complicated than truth tables can deal with. If $\forall x$ was defined via truth table, you would have to give meaning to the formula $P(x)$, so that $(\forall x)P(x)$ can have a truth value. But, $x$ is a variable, so, $P(x)$ isn't a claim that it makes sense to assign a truth value to, without a way of interpreting that variable.

Comment: hmm that makes sense, but then is there any way to check whether the given implication or equivalence involving quantifiers are true? In fact, I came across [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1590453/120111) problem, which I am able to solve it with the help of verbal interpretation, but not mathematically (can you also help me with solving this mathematically?). I was thinking if I can check them through some tool.

Comment: There is no procedure which, given a sentence in FOL, will return yes if it is a tautology, and no otherwise. This means that you have to approach in an ad hoc fashion. If you think it is true, try to give a proof, if you think it is false, try to find a counterexample.